# Getting AJAXToolkit Configured

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have searched for days trying to find answers about how to configure AJAX Toolkit to work on my ASP.NET VB.NET site.  I am having issues both with my development machine and on my hosing site.  I cannot find a good reference on the settings for the web.config file, and the reference in my webpage that will allow the controls to work.  Here is as much information that I have and I suspect most of it is wrong.  If anyone is actually using AJAXToolkit that comes with Visual Studio 2015 and could provide some guidance I would greatly appreciate it.  Here is the information I have.

My Configuration.
* Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (64bit)
* Hosting with GoDaddy who says they support AJAX but does not say if that is AJAX TOOLKIT.
* ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit Version 1.0
* .NET FRAMEWORK 4.1.41102.0
* Development in ASP.NET VB.NET code behind pages.
* AJAX toolkit has been installed on my development workstation version 17.1.0.0
web.config file has not been modified to reference AJAXToolkit as I have not found a good example for this version of AJAXtoolkit.

I have added the following lines to my web.config file in the following areas.

```
<assemblies>
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=17.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
</assemblies>

<controls>
   <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=17.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
</controls>
```

On my test page in the header section.

I am actually amazed at how confusing this is.  It almost appears that Microsoft has abandoned or never actually adopted AJAX.  One would think that simply dropping a component from the Tool Bar into your application should actually work.  But I have discovered that is far from the truth.

I have ventured down many different paths to resolve a problem on my site and the AJAX Tools will resolve it if only I can get any one of them to work.

Your help again is greatly appreciated.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

In all my pages I simply have this directive: 
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act" %> and have included AjaxControlToolkit in my project references

Comment: Adding this line <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act" %> in the page header area or any place in the page does not produce an error but when I try to add an Ajax Control Item I get "A ScriptManager is required on the page to use ASP.NET AJAX Script Components"

Comment: Here is my code.

        <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act" %>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
        <act:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="Calendar1" runat="server" />